# Javascript cookie remember me url redirect

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, cookies, hyperlink

I am quite new to using javascript, but i need it as i can not use PHP. Just good old HTML and Javascript.

What i need is a javascript cookie to remember to which url the visitor wants to be redirected after checking a checkbox.

My page has 3 links, each one links to another link ofcourse, but it would save time if visitors are redirected to the link they choose to remember.

Also i would need a simple button to delete that cookie if they choose to remember the wrong link.

Ofcourse i have searched Google and read some articles about it, but most of them tell all about remembering the username, i dont need that and i am not experienced enough to modify it to what i need.

Sorry if i am too unclear or confusing as i am Dutch.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. The people reading your question will read it as a request for custom coding rather than asking for help with a specific issue. Remembering a username or a URL is close enough for you to be able to use the code you have found, show it here and then ask for help with the actual code you wrote

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: euuuw. not [w3fools](http://w3fools.com)

Answer (score 0):

Examples for setting, getting and deleting cookies:

```
// sets the cookie cookie1
document.cookie =
 'cookie1=test; expires=Fri, 3 Aug 2001 20:47:11 UTC; path=/'

// sets the cookie cookie2 (cookie1 is *not* overwritten)
document.cookie =
 'cookie2=test; expires=Fri, 3 Aug 2001 20:47:11 UTC; path=/'

// gets cookie1 value
var cookie1Value = $.cookie("cookie1");

// gets cookie2 value    
var cookie2Value = $.cookie("cookie2");

// remove cookie2
document.cookie = 'cookie2=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/'
```